# Jquery draggable and clone

Tags: jquery

```
var icon = $("<div style='width:100px;height:100px;border-style:solid;'>");
icon.draggable({
    containment: 'parent',
    axis: 'y',
    drag: function(e,ui) { }
});
icon.clone(true).appendTo($("body"));
```

After I have made a clone, icon dragging stopped working.
Does anybody know, how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Call `draggable()` again on the clone?

Comment: `clone()` is not supported for `$.widget` widget factory in jquery UI [I read about this a few months back can't recall the link] may be because of that you see issues demo-ed by Ed Saito. you would have to $.clone(false) and apply draggable again.

Answer (score 4):

The draggable functionality **does not** stop working.

However, when you hold your mouse over the clone and move it around, it is the original element that gets dragged.

Click here to see this behaviour: http://www.jsfiddle.net/bxH3Q/

To get around this, you have to make each clone draggable.

Comment: Thanks guys for your involvment, but the problem that I use arcitecture of components creation once, and clones for showing them and hide removes clone. Each component has click, mouseover and so on, and everything works except DRAGGABLE =(

Answer (score 1):

What exactly you wanna do? Do you really need to clone?
You can use one of the `draggable()` options: `helper`, which clones the element as just as you drag. See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/nZm5H/

If you need to clone this way you do, you have to make the clone to be draggable also: [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nJbsU/)

Comment: your first example doesn't work, the pint here I think is that you should be able to clone all the events which is why the true is set as a clone parameter so you should have to call draggable on clone

Comment: @mcgrailm of course it's working. Maybe it's your borwser or browser settings. Look it through, buddy

Comment: Nope sorry man doesn't work I tried in ff 3.6.3 mac and safari mac and ie6 on xp